# Why isn't bash accepting any value for first element of array?

Tags: arrays, bash

So apparently arrays in bash have specials rules for what might be the first element, any explanation for this?

```
jgo ~$ myarray=(-n foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
foo
jgo ~$ myarray=(-v foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
-v foo
jgo ~$ myarray=(-a foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
-a foo
jgo ~$ myarray=(-e foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your output should look more like this:

```
jgo ~$ myarray=(-n foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
foojgo ~$ myarray=(-v foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
-v foo
jgo ~$ myarray=(-a foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
-a foo
jgo ~$ myarray=(-e foo) && echo ${myarray[@]}
foo
```

The reason is that `-n` and `-e` are valid options to `echo` whereas the other ones you tried aren't.

Comment: That's correct. I noticed when I tried it on a proper linux box, the output in the question is from cygwin.

Comment: good one. So if you use `printf` instead of `echo`, the output is fine. Also if you quote the elements in the array.

Comment: Or just add space before `$myarray` --> ` myarray=(-n foo) && echo " ${myarray[@]}"` if you still want to use echo

Comment: @Samuel Or as there is no reason to expand the array elements separately you could use  `echo "${myarray[*]}"` which keeps it all as a single arg to echo.